# Simpler SQL syntax? Which is better syntax?

Tags: sql

I have following sql syntax. This works fine but I was wondering if there is a way to write this syntax simpler since MAX(ra0.DescPriority) uses same table join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Items_1.ImageID, Items_1.SubcategoryID2, Items_1.AddDate,
                                 (SELECT        MAX(ra0.DescPriority) AS Expr1
                                   FROM            Items INNER JOIN
                                                             Attribs AS ra0 ON Items.ImageID = ra0.ImageID) AS Pri
    FROM            Items AS Items_1 INNER JOIN
                             Attribs AS ra0 ON Items_1.ImageID = ra0.ImageID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             v_DisplayStockPrice AS v_DisplayStockPrice_1 ON Items_1.ImageID = v_DisplayStockPrice_1.ImageID INNER JOIN
                             Attribs AS ra1 ON ra0.ImageID = ra1.ImageID
    WHERE        (Items_1.deleted NOT IN (1, 2)) AND (Items_1.SubcategoryID2 = 'ORD')
    ORDER BY Pri, Items_1.AddDate DESC
```

So I came up with this syntax.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Items_1.ImageID, Items_1.SubcategoryID2, Items_1.AddDate, MAX(ra0.DescPriority) AS Pri
FROM            Items AS Items_1 INNER JOIN
                         Attribs AS ra0 ON Items_1.ImageID = ra0.ImageID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         v_DisplayStockPrice AS v_DisplayStockPrice_1 ON Items_1.ImageID = v_DisplayStockPrice_1.ImageID INNER JOIN
                         Attribs AS ra1 ON ra0.ImageID = ra1.ImageID
WHERE        (Items_1.deleted NOT IN (1, 2)) AND (Items_1.SubcategoryID2 = 'ORD')
GROUP BY Items_1.ImageID, Items_1.SubcategoryID2, Items_1.AddDate
ORDER BY Pri, Items_1.AddDate DESC
```

Which SQL syntax is better? Or is there better way to write this Query?

Comment: You'll get better responses if you can boil down your examples to the essential difference you're asking about.

Comment: It's hard to understand queries that have a mixture of joins in the from clause, and subselects within the select clause (which are just an alternative form of join).  You should be consistent about how you express your joins.  Without studying your SQL in too much detail, I would prefer your second syntax example, because all the joins are expressed the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one looks better and probably performs better, but really you should use Query Analyzer. It will tell you exactly which one is better:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216945(v=sql.80).aspx

> Debug query performance problems. (Show Execution Plan, Show Server Trace, Show Client Statistics, Index Tuning Wizard)

Here's a description of how to use the query execution plan:
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/query-execution-plan-analysis/

Comment: I'll try query analyzer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used Sql Prompt to make your query look nicer here. Note that your third join is not doing anything and the pattern of INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN, INNER JOIN is incorrect, never use it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Items_1.ImageID ,
        Items_1.SubcategoryID2 ,
        Items_1.AddDate ,
        MAX(ra0.DescPriority) AS Pri
FROM    Items AS Items_1
        INNER JOIN Attribs AS ra0 ON Items_1.ImageID = ra0.ImageID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN v_DisplayStockPrice AS v_DisplayStockPrice_1 ON Items_1.ImageID = v_DisplayStockPrice_1.ImageID
        INNER JOIN Attribs AS ra1 ON ra0.ImageID = ra1.ImageID
WHERE   ( Items_1.deleted NOT IN ( 1, 2 ) )
        AND ( Items_1.SubcategoryID2 = 'ORD' )
GROUP BY Items_1.ImageID ,
        Items_1.SubcategoryID2 ,
        Items_1.AddDate
ORDER BY Pri ,
        Items_1.AddDate DESC
```

Comment: ... or at least if you need to mix inner joins and outer joins, use parentheses to make the join order clear.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Third join is for other conditions. Where clause will have more conditions using ra0 value.